# How to get HTML content of a website

Tags: ios, uiwebview, html-parsing, xcode4.3

In `viewDidLoad`, I'm using `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection`:

```
NSURLRequest *site_request = 
    [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"] 
                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                 timeoutInterval:10.0];

NSURLConnection *site_connection = 
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:site_request delegate:self];
```

and then I use

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)site_connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{    
    site_response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

and I have the whole HTML in `site_response`.

I want to create an invisible `UIWebView` which will "open" the page from the `NSURLRequest` in order to use JavaScript to get content like this:

```
NSString *myText = [my_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                       @"document.documentElement......"];
```

In my .h I have:

```
UIWebView *my_webview;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *my_webview;
```

and in my .m I have:

```
@synthesize torrents_webview;
```

My `viewDidLoad` after `NSURLRequest` has

```
[my_webview loadRequest:site_request];
```

and I use

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
    //an alertview here
}
```

in order to be sure it works.  But nothing happens.  It doesn't give an alert view.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webViewDidFinishLoad: is a method of the UIWebView delegate. You are not setting the delegate anywhere in the code you have shown.

```
@interface YourClass : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

...

- (void)loadView
{
    self.webView.delegate = self;
}


...
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.webView.delegate = nil;
}
```

Also if you use NSURLRequest you're going to get the page again. But there's no need to use NSURLConnection, just go straight to loading the UIWebVIew using the NSURLRequest.

Or if you must use NSURLConnection then when the file has downloaded save it to disk and use LoadHTMLString  to load the contents.

Comment: thanks for answering , i added delegate twice as you suggested but it didn't work , i didn't add - (void)dealloc
{
    self.webView.delegate = nil;
} i can avoid the NSURLConnection , but tell me something when i create the NSURLRequest at viewDidLoad , it immediately gets the contents of the page ??

Comment: Creating a NSURLRequest wont get anything, but you are passing the request to an NSURLConnection which will get the request when you start it (which I presumed you were doing but not showing the next line, otherwise why have an NSURLConnection?)

Comment: Ok i removed NSURLConnection i understood it doesn't need to be there thank you too. Probably i'm missing the part of "will get the request when you start it"

Comment: Are you still having problems? Post an update of your latest code

Answer (score 0):

ViewController.h

```
@interface TopTorrents_ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    UIWebView *torrents_webview;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *torrents_webview;
```

ViewController.m

```
    @synthesize torrents_webview;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{       
    torrents_webview.delegate = self;

    NSURLRequest *site_request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.gr/"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];

    [torrents_webview loadRequest:site_request];  

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

    -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
    {
        NSString *myText = [torrents_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]"];

    UIAlertView *my_alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"mytitle" message:myText delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"my button" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];

    [my_alert show];

}
```

this is my updated code... thanks

Comment: Where are you creating the UIWebView?

Comment: what do you mean where im creating it ? at ViewController.h i have these 2 lines and at ViewController.m im trying to "tell" it which site to visit. i dont want to "view" the webview , i want it to load a site and to be hidden.

Comment: Objects in Objective-C have to be created somewhere, somehow before they can be used by using alloc or using Interface Builder. As your torrents_webview does not have an IBOutlet I presume you are not using Interface Builder? So my question is where is your call to alloc to create torrents_webview? Let me ask an alternate question, in viewDidLoad, what is the value of torrents_webview if you view it in the debugger or NSLog it. In other words is it nil or not?

Comment: i added     CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];  
    torrents_webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];  and solved my problem , thanks !

Comment: I'd be greateful  if you could accept the answer, if it helped.